# How to build px4_drv kernel module in NixOS?

Tags: linux, module, kernel, nixos

I'm following this instruction: https://github.com/nns779/px4_drv

`make` under the directory `fwtool` builds `it930x-firmware.bin`
and `make` under `driver` builds `px4_drv` kernel module.

I wrote these two nix expr:

```
$ cat ./it930x.nix
{ stdenv, fetchFromGitHub, fetchzip }:

stdenv.mkDerivation rec {
  pname = "it930x-firmware";
  version = "1";

  src = fetchFromGitHub {
    owner = "nns779";
    repo = "px4_drv";
    rev = "90e0a4b30b812e7e5fff4483144f165de8914157";
    sha256 = "1s9y5szv9i8dj6pnbkph48nikzf1bhkj592pczbq7hy31xr60hmw";
  };
  plexSrc = fetchzip {
    url = "http://plex-net.co.jp/plex/pxw3u4/pxw3u4_BDA_ver1x64.zip";
    sha256 = "1ky28m8hv86vivk2clps5qpmlrmlvfya8qcfmcvpd3n2kisbqsrl";
  };

  sourceRoot = "fwtool/";

  postUnpack = ''
    cp "$plexSrc/pxw3u4_BDA_ver1x64/PXW3U4.sys" .
  '';

  installPhase = ''
    mkdir -p $out/lib/firmware/
    ./fwtool PXW3U4.sys $out/lib/firmware/it930x-firmware.bin
  '';

  meta = with stdenv.lib; {
    description = "it930x-firmware for px4_drv";
    homepage = https://github.com/nns779/px4_drv;
    license = licenses.gpl2;
  };
}
```

```
$ cat ./px4_drv.nix
{ stdenv, fetchFromGitHub, kernel, it930x-firmware }:

stdenv.mkDerivation rec {
  pname = "px4_drv";
  version = "1";

  src = fetchFromGitHub {
    owner = "nns779";
    repo = "px4_drv";
    rev = "90e0a4b30b812e7e5fff4483144f165de8914157";
    sha256 = "1s9y5szv9i8dj6pnbkph48nikzf1bhkj592pczbq7hy31xr60hmw";
  };

  sourceRoot = "driver/";

  hardeningDisable = [ "pic" ];

  KERNELDIR = "${kernel.dev}/lib/modules/${kernel.modDirVersion}/build";
  INSTALL_MOD_PATH = "\${out}";

  NIX_CFLAGS = ["-Wno-error=cpp"];

  nativeBuildInputs = [ it930x-firmware ] ++ kernel.moduleBuildDependencies;

  buildFlags = [ "module" ];
  installTargets = [ "module-install" ];

  meta = with stdenv.lib; {
    description = "Kernel module px4_drv";
    homepage = https://github.com/nns779/px4_drv;
    license = licenses.gpl2;
    platforms = platforms.linux;
  };
}
```

(The original two code is borrowed from `b43-firmware` and `wireguard`.)

and include these by below way:

```
$ cat ./configuration.nix
{ config, lib, pkgs, ... }:
let
  px4_drv = pkgs.callPackage ./px4_drv.nix;
  it930x = pkgs.callPackage ./it930x.nix;
in {
  boot.extraModulePackages = [
    (px4_drv {
      it930x-firmware = it930x;
      kernel = pkgs.linux_4_19;
    })
  ];
  boot.kernelPackages = pkgs.linuxPackages_4_19;
  ...
}
```

The result is:

```
$ sudo nixos-rebuild test
error: cannot coerce a function to a string, at /nix/store/8zwm55m0754cn9cv6inwm469h0my219r-nixos-20.09pre218482.3320a06049f/nixos/pkgs/stdenv/generic/make-derivation.nix:191:11
(use '--show-trace' to show detailed location information)
```

`nix-shell -E "with import <nixpkgs> {}; callPackage ./px4_drv.nix { it930x-firmware = callPackage ./it930x.nix; kernel = linux_4_19; }"`
results the same.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the second argument to `callPackage` is missing. You can use it to override inputs to a package or provide extra inputs.
In `configuration.nix`, try

```
  px4_drv = pkgs.callPackage ./px4_drv.nix { it930x-firmware = it930x; };
  it930x = pkgs.callPackage ./it930x.nix {};
```

Comment: Great first step! but `chmod: cannot access 'fwtool': No such file or directory`

Comment: `sourceRoot` and dest of `cp` on `postUnpack` should be `source/fwtool`. `it930x.nix` is complete but `px4_drv.nix` not fires.

Comment: Almost completed! https://gist.github.com/gtgteq/30cb73c344477d26f8c69768e010331a